# Make image take up 100% of the height, but not 100% of the height (and keep image same dimensions when zooming out)

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: Thanks to minitech, got it working much closer than it was before. I used 'cover' for background size and it no longer resizes when zooming in/out (as hoped), but the image is also way too big now. Is there any way around this?

Thanks again.

...

Original Post:

I'm making a website where I'd like for the left column to be an image that takes up 100% of the height and 30ish% of the width of whatever resolution the user is browsing it on. Also, if they zoom in/out, I'd like for the image to resize so that it still maintains the full height of the browser.

I tried using the following javascript to set the width/height of a containing div in pixels, and then adjust the rest with percentages:

`document.write('<div id="container" style="width: ' + window.innerWidth + 'px; height: ' +  window.innerHeight + 'px;">');`

It doesn't work quite as I had anticipated (not readjusting the dimensions) and is either taller or shorter than the viewing height on several browsers/resolutions I've tested it with (especially on iPad).

The site is http://lesliecampbellweddings.com/.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: 100% of the height... but not 100% of the height?

Comment: See [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: [This article may be of interest.](http://daverupert.com/2012/04/uncle-daves-ol-padded-box/) The idea is to use the fact that padding measurements for both height and width are always figured relative to element width when the value is a percentage.

Comment: Uhh forcing the width to 100% is making me crazy on my mobile if i try to zoom into an image for reading a much to small text.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use absolute positioning:

```css
#container {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://dabblet.com/gist/4032390)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't need any JavaScript and just need to use `background-attachment:fixed;` for your left column.

Check out this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ckukT/

Here is your HTML for this example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-col">
    </div>
    <div id="right-col">
        <p>Random text and content that would be needed goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And here is the respective CSS:

```
#wrapper {height:100%; width:100%;}

#left-col {
    background: url("http://www.lesliecampbellweddings.com/images/brideAndGroom.jpg") top center fixed no-repeat;
    width:50%;
    height:900px;
    float:left;
}

#right-col {
    background: yellow; /* so you can see it*/
    width:50%;
    height:900px;
    float:left;
}
```

​

Instead of center top for the background positioning feel free to use fixed pixels, but center will keep the photo centered despite the width or size of the browser, and top will keep it to always show the top - you could use center center if you always want the middle of the image shown. You can play with this but ideally, I assume you would keep her face always shown.